# Why is my font encoding not working, despite setting "setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");"?

Tags: c++, fonts

Hey guys ı have a question about my code. I think I made everything correctly. But ı have a font disorder. How can I fix it? I'm using `"setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");"` but the Turkish symbol is still not being interpreted correctly.

Here is my code:

```
//Klavyeden girilen 2 sayıdan küçüğünü bulup tekmi çiftmi olduğunu ekran 
yazdırınız...

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
int x, y;


cout << "Birinci Sayıyı Giriniz:";
cin >> x;

cout << "İkinci Sayıyı Giriniz:";
cin >> y;

if (x < y && ((x % 2) == 0))
{
    cout << "İlk sayı ikinci sayıdan küçük ve çifttir.";
}
else if (x < y && ((x % 2) == 1))
{
    cout << "İlk sayı ikinci sayıdan küçük ve tektir.";
}
else if (y < x && ((x % 2) == 1))
{
    cout << "İlk sayı ikinci sayıdan büyük ve tektir.";
}
else
{
    cout << "İlk sayı ikinci sayıdan büyük ve çifttir..";
}



system("PAUSE");
return 0;}
```

Here is the text in my code:

[image]

And here is the output which shows some garbling:

[image]

Comment: [Edit] your question to post your code as text and not pictures. Hurry before it gets closed.

Comment: `cmd` is using a different character encoding than VS Code

Comment: Im not usıng VS Code, Im using Visual Studio 2019 IDE

Comment: What symbol are you using for "I" there? You use it again here in your question in the first sentence. Use the normal "I" character instead.

Comment: @EJoshuaS dude ım meanıng Im writing "ı" (without pointed "i"). This is a turkish symbol. But ı was writed  "setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");". But ı have this bug or error or samething... Do u understand?

Comment: @TylerH it is İ without point.

Answer (score 2):

The issue maybe because of the cmd using default code page 850 instead of UTF-8

To make cmd use UTF-8, do the following*:

1. Type `chcp 65001` in cmd, if it didn't work follow the steps below.
2. Start -> Run -> regedit
3. Go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun]`
4. Change the value to `chcp 65001`
5. Restart your system.

*Do it at your own risk as you are dealing with the Windows registry.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/269857/1033757)

Following are the code page numbers for reference purpose, I see you are using Turkish so you might also want to use code `857`. [Image source](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)

[image: Code page codes]

Comment: I don't have "autorun" in there. Only I have (Default, CompletionChar, DefaultColor, EnableExtensions, PathCompletionChar)

Comment: The reason is that the output console uses Latin encoding(850) while you want to display non Lating letters also, so I suggest you follow the steps to use UTF-8.

Comment: Guys I dont have "autorun" in there look at this photo https://imgur.com/a/aPzLbRz

Comment: Add the field then

Comment: or run `chcp 65001` in cmd

Comment: I runned "chcp 65001" in cmd. What else I need to do ?

Comment: Reboot the system then check whether the encoding is set to 65001 by typing `chcp` in cmd, you should get the encoding code: 65001, just for conformation.

Comment: When ı write it in cmd I see nothing happening.

Comment: Ok ım rebootıng ım comıng 1 min.

Comment: Official source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp

Comment: Uhhh :( It doesn't work. Its already 857. Anyway thanks for help bro. I wıll be use U.S. letters. :)

Comment: Maybe this would work: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rrasblog/2009/03/13/change-in-username-format-to-utf8-to-handle-international-characters/